# NextJS: Image warning error "Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally."

Tags: next.js, next-images

Got this error message on the console

> The resource "xxx.svg" was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.[image]

And here is my code

```
import Image from 'next/image'

<Image src={xxx} width={32} height={24} priority />
```

[image: Here is my code]

I expect to do the correct next image rendering with `Priority` attribute without the warning message.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this because I had a default image in the largest contentful paint, but when it needed to look up an image it gave me this warning if I used the priority attribute.
So I simply enabled priority only for the default attribute and that solved it for me. Something like this:

```js
<Image
  priority={use_default ? true : false}
  ...
/>
```